# disable quickedit for specific custom post type user role

Tags: custom-post-types, user-roles, quick-edit

I seem to be missing something fundamental somehow ('ll try and keep it short but can provide more code if needs be of course )

I have registered a CPT with following arguments

```
'capability_type' => array(CPT_SLUG, CPT_SLUG.'s'),
'map_meta_cap' => true,
 'capabilities' => array(
 'edit_post' => 'edit_'.CPT_SLUG.'',
 'edit_posts' => 'edit_'.CPT_SLUG.'s',
 'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_others_'.CPT_SLUG.'s',
 'publish_posts' => 'publish_'.CPT_SLUG.'s',
 'read_post' => 'read_'.CPT_SLUG.'',
 'read_private_posts' => 'read_private_'.CPT_SLUG.'s',
 'delete_post' => 'delete_'.CPT_SLUG.'',
 'delete_posts' => 'delete_'.CPT_SLUG.'s'
 )
```

so far so good. to bring things in line somewhat with the way user roles work in normal wp posts I am removing the capability for "author" roles by doing

```
 $authorRole->remove_cap( 'edit_others_'.CPT_SLUG.'s' );
```

so authors cannot edit the post of other roles. though this works, I am still left with the quick edit link in the list of CPT posts even for posts created by another role.

although I cannot save anything using the quick edit for posts created by other roles (which is the idea of course), I don't think that quick edit link should be there, to begin with (for example "normal" WP posts don't show this either in above scenario)

am I missing a filter/action perhaps I need to add too? or is there another capability that needs removing for the "author"?

had a look around for quite some time now but cannot find any answer really other than what seems workarounds...

hints much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [`post_row_actions`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_row_actions/) hook:

```
/**
 * Hide quick edit
 *
 * @internal  Used as a callback.
 *
 * @see  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/post_row_actions/
 */
function wpse288663_hide_quick_edit($actions, $post)
{
    // Replace `{$cap}` with your specific capability.
    if (CPT_SLUG === $post->post_type && current_user_can({$cap})) {
        unset($actions['inline hide-if-no-js']);
    }

    return $actions;
}

// Hook up.
add_filter('post_row_actions', 'wpse288663_hide_quick_edit', 10, 2);
```

Comment: hmm, that only works in so far as that it removes *all* links (quickedit as well as view and probably all others ) for *all* posts (i.e also for the posts that belong to the author role)

maybe i need to clarify: I only want the quickedit links to disappear for posts that where NOT created by the "author" role. 
the posts that belong to the "author" role should be "quickeditable"

Comment: actually - sorry about that - i think i might have made an error here (way too late - again )
i'll mess around for a bit after some sleep. I think my comment above is not strictly accurate 
thanks for taking the time to reply .

Comment: I corrected the hook by changing `add_action` ==> `add_filter`. Hope it work for you!

Comment: It turns out that my problem was that I actually already used the `post_row_actions` hook to add a customised quick edit link previously without accounting for the user role, so instead of trying to remove something I should not have added it in the first place like I did . Doh !
a simple conditional in my original function hooked like so 
`$can_edit_post    = current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post->ID );      
if ( !$can_edit_post || 'trash' == $post->post_status ) {return $actions;}` 
solved my problem. I'll accept the answer provided (and it also brought me onto the trail of the issue)